# relationships, crud silex and propel orm

Tags: php, symfony, propel, silex

I'm trying something new on my app, as the way I was doing it before wasnt really optimal, it was possible to repeat currencies endlessly in the currency table, which is not what I really want in the future(thinking of scalability and future growth).

So I went ahead, and reading on the documentation and in [ORM Cheatsheet](http://ormcheatsheet.com/propel/) got a many-to-many (not exactly what I want but its ok, as it works again thinking of scalability and future growth)

```
<xml>
<table name="countries">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="128" required="true" />
    <column name="country_code" phpName="CountryCode" type="VARCHAR" size="7" required="true" />
    <column name="status" phpName="Status" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false" />

    <unique name="IX_UQ_banks_id">
        <unique-column name="id"/>
    </unique>

    <unique name="IX_UQ_currencies_id">
        <unique-column name="id"/>
    </unique>

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="soft_delete" />
    <behavior name="versionable" />
</table>

<table name="currencies">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="128" required="true" />
    <column name="code" phpName="Code" type="VARCHAR" size="7" required="true" />
    <column name="symbol" phpName="Symbol" type="VARCHAR" size="12" required="true" />

    <unique name="IX_UQ_countries_id">
        <unique-column name="id"/>
    </unique>

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="soft_delete" />
</table>

<table name="country_has_currency" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="countries_id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" />
    <column name="currencies_id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" />

    <foreign-key
        foreignTable="countries"
        defaultJoin="Criteria::LEFT_JOIN"
        onDelete="setnull"
        onUpdate="cascade"
        phpName="Countries">
        <reference local="countries_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>

    <foreign-key
        foreignTable="currencies"
        defaultJoin="Criteria::INNER_JOIN"
        onDelete="setnull"
        onUpdate="cascade">
        <reference local="currencies_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

```

What I cant seem to find is the proper way to save this objects once I insert new records.
due to the code I'm writing I can get the currency a country has using the Intl component of symfony2 (im using silex tho), so the problem arises here:

Add new country, get currency, check if currency exists, if so, create a relationship with existing currency and new country, if it doesnt exist, insert both new country and new currency.

Answer (score 0):

got it.

```
<!-- language: php -->
$country = new Countries();
$country->setName($data['country_name']);
$country->setCountryCode($data['country_code']);
$country->setStatus($data['country_status']);

$currency = new Currencies();
$currency->setName($data['currency_name']);
$currency->setCode($data['currency_code']);
$currency->setSymbol($data['currency_symbol']);

$country->addCurrencies($currency);

$country->save();
```